# google maps v3 kml layers not displaying

Tags: jquery, google-maps, kml

I have created a jquery/google maps page that hides/displays KML layers using:

```
GLOBAL.ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://www.test.com/akml.kml'
});
GLOBAL.ctaLayer.setMap(map);
```

This code works fine but for some reason it works when a access a KML from a windows 2003 server. I am moving the site to a new server that is Windows Server 2012 and now the kmls do not display when I call the above code. I have KML set up in the Mime Types. Permissions on the folders are the same as the old server... I've tried everything I can think of to no avail. I've even completely disabled the Firewall...

Anyone have any issues accessing KML layers on a Windows Server 2012 or a solution on how to fix??

Comment: Are you able to access your URL `http://www.test.com/akml.kml` directly from the browser?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut#kml_server

Comment: Yes - it asks if I want to download the file when I put the url in directly - but it does not display the KML when I using the code above. If I change the url to my other server - the same KML displays fine

Comment: Thanks for the link geocodezip - but I have the mime type defined correctly and the KML file is correct...

Comment: What do the websniffers say? ([http://web-sniffer.net/](http://web-sniffer.net/) or [http://www.rexswain.com/httpview.html](http://www.rexswain.com/httpview.html)) What about the [KML validator](http://www.feedvalidator.org/)?

Comment: The site is password protected and redirects when not logged in which makes it difficult to use web-sniffer.net... it just returns the log in info

Comment: I have the same KML on 2 servers. When I load the KML from one server it displays fine. When I change the url to the new server it does not display...

Comment: If it is password protected, then you can't host your KML on it (at least for use with KmlLayer).  To use it with KmlLayer, it has to be _publicly available_.

Comment: ok - finally discovered that it's not a server issue. It seems that if I type the url for the file in directly to the script it works. I am dynamically creating the url for the KML and when I designate the url with a variable name it doesn't work... GLOBAL.ctaLayer['layer'] = new google.maps.KmlLayer({ url: useurl });

Comment: it doesn't seem like you can access `http://www.test.com/akml.kml`